# Asp.Net - IEnumerable properties not binding to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I get a `NullPointerException` error when I attempt to render `@Model.Columns` in the View. I'm using LinqToExcel.

Relevant code parts:

Model:

```
namespace steer.Models
{
    public class UpFile
    {
        // Irrelevant properties (name,size,filetype) omitted

        public IEnumerable<string> Columns { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LinqToExcel.Row> Rows { get; set; }

        public class UpFileDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<UpFile> UpFiles { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

View:

```
  @model steer.Models.UpFile

  @foreach (var item in Model.Columns)
  {
     <th>@item</th>
  }
```

Controller:

```
UpFile up = new UpFile();
// Name, size, filetype binding omitted

// Here I attempt to bind Columns and Rows from uploaded Excel file
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploaded\\" + up.Name);
var firstSheet = excel.GetWorksheetNames().First();
// Rows is IEnumerable
up.Rows = from c in excel.Worksheet(firstSheet)
    select c;
// GetColumnNames returns a List. up.Columns property is IEnumerable.
up.Columns = excel.GetColumnNames(firstSheet);
db.UpFiles.Add(up);
db.SaveChanges();
```

`Name`, `size`, `filetype` are set just fine. But the `columns` and `rows` properties are always empty.

The extraction of the Excel file also works fine, as I can directly send the Excel rows successfully to the view. It is only when I try to reference the properties that I have troubles.

```
// GET: files/details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    UpFile upFile = db.UpFiles.Find(id);
    if (upFile == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(upFile);
}
```

Also!! When I insert Breakpoint at `db.SaveChanges()`, all the data is there

Comment: Are you doing `return View(up);` in your controller?

Comment: @br4d yes, I do. Not in this function, though, because this is just the upload and binding,.

Comment: Can you post that code? We need to see whatever action you have populating the `steer.Models.UpFile` that is strongly typed to the view.

Comment: Oh, right. I have added to the post

Comment: What does `upFile` look like after you get it from `Find`?

Comment: ´upFile´ at that point looks like this: Everything is normal, except rows and columns is null.

Comment: Have you actually looked in the DB itself to see if the rows and columns were being saved?

Comment: DefaultConnection DB doesn't have Columns nor Rows. I ran add-migration and update-database.